# Comparing proportions in dynamic populations

Tags: proportion, pre-post-comparison, method-comparison

I have an example of dataset like this:

| Members of insurance plan | 01.01.2021 | 01.01.2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <18 y. o | 2100 | 3000 |
| Total members | 200000 | 230000 |

How can I compare proportions and define if proportion on 01.01.2021 (2100/200000) is statistically significant differ from proportion on 01.01.2022 (3000/230000)?

Also here we're dealing with dynamic population, e.g., some of members of insurance plan still may be members on 01.01.2022 and some not and vise versa (may not be member on 01.01.2021 but became member on 01.01.2022).

Comment: Sounds like you are maybe interested not in proportions, but in **change in proportions?** For example, $\Delta p_{t=1} = p_{t=1} - p_{t=0}$?

Comment: @Alexis, hmmm, yes, I guess you're right.

Comment: @Alexis I've found estimation for proportion difference in random sample. But does estimation differ in random sample and dynamic population?

Comment: I mean,one way of thinking about it is that it's not comparing two proportions, but two changes in proportion *a la* $\text{H}_0\text{: }\Delta p_{<18\text{yo}} - \Delta p_{18+\text{yo}} = 0$? What is the research question you want to answer?

Comment: @Alexis the research question is "Does proportion of members of insurance plan <18 y. o. in 2021 statistically significant differ from proportion of members <18 y. o. in 2022?"